# NSUnknownKeyException when filtering an array by NSPredicate

Tags: ios, nsstring, nspredicate, nsunknownkeyexception

I have a really annoying bug. May be there is a trivial solution, but I can't get it.

I use `NSPredicate` often without any problem. Now the following bug comes: Terminating app due to uncaught exception '`NSUnknownKeyException`', reason: '`[<TestClass 0x10cf3b80> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key testValue.`'

```
NSString* predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@",@"testValue"];
NSPredicate* filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
NSArray* filtered = [all filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];
```

name is an `NSString*` property of my class, all is an array with my objects in it. Just some trivial code, nothing extra.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you construct the predicate as an NSString it should be (note the extra quotes):

```objc
NSString* predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] '%@'", @"testValue"];
```

Alternatively you can build it more directly with:

```objc
NSPredicate* filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"testValue"];
```

The second method automatically puts quotes around arguments with the %@ specifier.

Comment: Uhh, what a mistake by me. Thanks. I should sleep more and work less.